# Matrix encoding implementation in the F5 steganography algorithm is unclear

Tags: java, steganography

I need to implement my own F5 algorithm. I have read the F5 documentation and the paper can be found [here](https://f5-steganography.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release-0.3/F5%20Steganography.pdf).

In the section *6.2 Matrix Encoding* of the paper, equations 16-18 define the change density, `D(k)`, the embedding rate, `R(k)` and the efficiency rate, `W(k)`, as follows:

```
D(k) = 1 / (n + 1) = 1 / 2**k

R(k) = k / n = k / (2**k - 1)

W(k) = R(k) / D(k) = k * 2**k / (2**k - 1)
```

Where `n` is the number of modifiable places in a code word and `k` the number of embedding bits. `W(k)` indicats the average number of bits we can embed per change.

In the source code we find the number of bits as stated below. Can someome please explain why `usable` and `changed` are calculated this way? I simply don't understand the logic.

```
    int _changed = 0;
    int _expected = 0;
    int _one = 0;
    int _large = 0;
    int _zero = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < coeffCount; i++) {
        if (i % 64 == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        if (coeff[i] == 1) {
            _one++;
        }
        if (coeff[i] == -1) {
            _one++;
        }
        if (coeff[i] == 0) {
            _zero++;
        }
    }
    _large = coeffCount - _zero - _one - coeffCount / 64;
    _expected = _large + (int) (0.49 * _one);
for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    int usable, changed, n;
    n = (1 << i) - 1;
    usable = _expected * i / n - _expected * i / n % n;
    changed = coeffCount - _zero - coeffCount / 64;
    changed = changed * i / n - changed * i / n % n;
    changed = n * changed / (n + 1) / i;
    //
    changed = _large - _large % (n + 1);
    changed = (changed + _one + _one / 2 - _one / (n + 1)) / (n + 1);
    usable /= 8;
    if (usable == 0) {
        break;
    }
    if (i == 1) {
        System.out.print("default");
    } else {
        System.out.print("(1, " + n + ", " + i + ")");
    }
    System.out.println(" code: " + usable + " bytes (efficiency: " + usable * 8 / changed + "." + usable * 8
            / changed % 10 + " bits per change)");
}
```

coeff is an array that holds the DCT coefficients,coeffCount is the number of DCT coefficients,_large is the teoretical number of bits from the image that can be encoded and expected is the expected capacity of the image(with shrinkage).I don't understand what is the logic behind usable and changed variables

Comment: The line `changed = _large - _large % (n + 1);` will effectively overwrite `changed` irrelevantly to its previous value. Is there supposed to be a comment somewhere there? It would be helpful to provide a link to the source code with a reference where the code snippet occurs. Can you also please describe what any variables not initialised in this code block represent and what values they hold?

Comment: Reti43         I modified the question.The source code is the source code from the F5  algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last paragraph of the section 6.2 in the paper says the following and I quote:

> We can ﬁnd an optimal parameter k for every message to embed and every
>   carrier medium providing suﬃcient capacity, so that the message just ﬁts into the
>   carrier medium. For instance, if we want to embed a message with 1000 bits into
>   a carrier medium with a capacity of 50000 bits, then the necessary embedding
>   rate is R = 1000 : 50000 = 2 %. This value is between R(k = 8) and R(k = 9) in
>   Table 1. We choose k = 8, and are able to embed 50000 : 255 = 196 code words
>   with a length n = 255. The (1, 255, 8) code could embed 196 · 8 = 1568 bits. If
>   we chose k = 9 instead, we could not embed the message completely.

I believe this should be straightforward. If you can understand this, you can follow the steps below.

One more preliminary thing is the expression `result = var - var % n;` throughout the code. This means you make `var` exactly divisible by `n` by removing the remainder (modulo operation). Now onto the loop block.

```
n = 1 << i - 1
```

This is the code word length, as defined in the paper.

---

```
usable = _expected * i / n - _expected * i / n % n;
```

To understand this line, remember that `i / n` is the embedding rate, R(i). In simple words, the number of possibly available bits (`_expected`) times the embedding rate (`i / n`), gives the number of bit we can encode. In the example from the quote that's 50000 / 255 * 8 = 1568 bits.

---

```
changed = coeffCount - _zero - coeffCount / 64;
changed = changed * i / n - changed * i / n % n;
changed = n * changed / (n + 1) / i;
```

The first line says that the number of bits that we can go through (call this *total*) is the number of coefficients (`coeffCount`), while skipping any zeros and the DC component of each 8x8 block (`coeffCount / 64`). Each 8x8 block has 64 coefficients, but only one is the DC coefficient, so every 64 coefficients you have one more DC coefficient to skip.

The second and third lines go together. Notice than in the second line you multiply by the embedding rate and you make that result perfectly divisible by the code word length. In the third line you divide by the embedding rate, thereby *cancelling* the previous step, and then you multiply by the change density, `1 / (n + 1)`, to find the number of bits to be changed on average.

The reason you go through this whole process is because the order of divisions and multiplications matter. As a straightforward example, consider you have 150 bits and 7 items that you want to distribute evenly into as many bits as possible. How many bits will you need overall?

```
7 * (150 / 7) = 7 * 21 = 147
```

---

**Note**: The following lines overwrite the currently computed value of `changed`. The previous 3 lines and the following 2 independently tend to give similar answers when I make up my own `_one`, `_zero`, `coeffCount` values. One of these two versions may be old code which was not removed. Regardless, the logic is the following.

```
changed = _large - _large % (n + 1);
changed = (changed + _one + _one / 2 - _one / (n + 1)) / (n + 1);
```

The first line has to do with the change density, D(i), since you make the expression perfectly divisible by `n + 1`. Because of how `_large` is defined, this is similar to how `changed` is computed in the previous version.

```
_large = coeffCount - _zero - _one - coeffCount / 64;
```

Which bears close resemblance to this

```
changed = coeffCount - _zero - coeffCount / 64;
```

The next line is a little bit hazy to me, but this is what it seems to achieve. It reintroduces back the `_one` it substracted in `_large` and one half of the ones. This is due to shrinkage, since it replicates the idea in `_expected = _large + int(0.49*_ones)`. I don't quite understand why you would substract `ones / (n + 1)`, but multiplying this whole expression by the change density, `1 / (n + 1)`, you get the number of bits you expect to change.

### **Conclusion**

The two ways for calculating the expected number of bits to change are not exact and it has to do with not knowing in advance exactly how many will be changed. They both seem to give similar results for given values of `_zero`, `_one` and `coeffCount`. None of this is really necessary as it just estimates the efficiency for different `k` as in the quote. You just need to find the maximum `k` for which you use as much of the carrier medium to embed your information. This is done by just calculating `usable` and breaking the loop as soon as you don't have enough bits to embed your message. And this exact thing is done a bit further down in the source code.